# Too many connections error when I connect in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, csv, pdo

I try to load csv file through PHP and my csv file has lot of records (300). When load the csv file process, it only upload 25 rows then PDO error appear "Too many connections". Is there any way that faster the insert process?

```
while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){    
   try{    
      $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);    
      $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    
      $stmt = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO Growth(id, date, stage, length, width) VALUES(nullif('$emapData[0]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[1]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[2]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[3]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[4]','NULL')");
      $stmt->execute();
   }
   catch(PDOException $e){
      echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set your database connection `$dbcon` first before calling your insert statements.

```
$dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,$password);

while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){    
    try{        
        $dbcon->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    $stmt   = $dbcon->prepare("INSERT INTO Growth(id, date, stage, length, width) VALUES(nullif('$emapData[0]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[1]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[2]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[3]','NULL'), nullif('$emapData[4]','NULL')");

        $stmt->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stack Overflow is taken by many as a service to provide a quick fix to an immediate problem at hand.

Unfortunately, it is also a source of the reusable code examples. And when you look at this site from such a point of view, you will find most answers *appalling*, as they create more problems than solve.

Take, for example, this post. The code in the OP is wrong on *many* levels, essentially misusing a prepared statement, ditching *all* its benefits. Well, it's all right, actually, as we are all learning. But the *answer* is leaving all the problems intact, focusing on a single particular problem. As a result, we have an *approved by the community* code example that is, actually, *extremely harmful*. All right, I've got some experience to tell a bad code. But an unsuspecting visitor from Google doesn't. And would simply copy and paste the offered solution. Along with all its vulnerabilities and inefficiency.

To run a prepared statement in a loop:

- of course the connection should be made before the loop

  - besides, all the connection code have to be moved outside the loop, not only a part of it
  - besides, it have to be a correct connection code, with all the required options, so it won't introduce new problems in the future (caused by the wrong `charset` for example)
- the prepared statement should be the actual prepared statement, not an imitation. **All variables in the query must be replaced with placeholders** to make this prepared statement actually do anything useful - preventing an **SQL injection** in the first place.
- the `prepare()` call must be **moved out of the loop** as well. That's the very point of such a statement - *prepare* once, execute multiple.
- the error handling code must be secure and flexible. While `echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();` is anything than it.

So the correct example would be:

```
include 'pdo.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO Growth(id, date, stage, length, width)
VALUES(nullif(?,'NULL'), nullif(?,'NULL'), nullif(?,'NULL'), nullif(?,'NULL'), nullif(?,'NULL')")
$stmt = $dbcon->prepare($sql);
while(($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE){    
    $stmt->execute($emapData);
}
```

Two assumptions were made in this code:

- the `pdo.php` file contains a [correct PDO connection code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql) as instead of connecting in the every file the connection code must be moved in a separate file and then just included in every script that requires a database connection
- the number of columns in the csv file is equal to the number of rows in the table. Otherwise, an `array_slice()` function must be called on `$emapData` beforehand